# Extract HTML data using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup, informatica

I have a table with ID,TEXT,etc columns Here TEXT is clob column which contains data in HTML FORMAT

**SAMPLE DATA :**

```
<P class=00Normal style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt 24.3pt"><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Start: 8:30 am<?xml:namespace prefix = o ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" /><o:p></o:p></SPAN></P>
<P class=00Normal style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt 24.3pt"><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">End: 4 pm<o:p></o:p></SPAN></P>
<P class=00Normal style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt 24.3pt"><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">The goal of this visit is to conduct an intial assessment of systems and processes in place to support supply of materials for GMP clinical development and manufacturing of pharmaceuticals.<SPAN style="mso-spacerun: yes">  </SPAN>A cGMP assessment of specific processes, procedures, ad the general quality systems will occur as outlined below.<SPAN style="mso-spacerun: yes">  </SPAN>The following items represent the scope and visit focus areas:<o:p></o:p></SPAN></P>
<P class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt 60.3pt; TEXT-INDENT: -0.25in; tab-stops: list 60.3pt; mso-list: l120 level1 lfo139"><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; mso-bidi-font-weight: bold">1.<SPAN style="FONT: 7pt 'Times New Roman'">       </SPAN></SPAN><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; mso-bidi-font-weight: bold">SOP Program<o:p></o:p></SPAN></P>
<P class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt 0.9in; TEXT-INDENT: -22.5pt"><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; mso-bidi-font-weight: bold"> <o:p></o:p></SPAN></P>
<P class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt 60.3pt; TEXT-INDENT: -0.25in; tab-stops: list 60.3pt; mso-list: l120 level1 lfo139"><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; mso-bidi-font-weight: bold">2.<SPAN style="FONT: 7pt 'Times New Roman'">       </SPAN></SPAN><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; mso-bidi-font-weight: bold">Training Program<o:p></o:p></SPAN></P>
<P class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt 0.9in; TEXT-INDENT: -22.5pt"><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; mso-bidi-font-weight: bold"> <o:p></o:p></SPAN></P>
<P class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt 60.3pt; TEXT-INDENT: -0.25in; tab-stops: list 60.3pt; mso-list: l120 level1 lfo139"><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; mso-bidi-font-weight: bold">3.<SPAN style="FONT: 7pt 'Times New Roman'">       </SPAN></SPAN><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; mso-bidi-font-weight: bold">Calibration/Preventive Maintenance Program<o:p></o:p></SPAN></P>
```

I'm using java transformation imported with Jsoup.jar file in informatica.
When I use **Jsoup.parse(AUDIT_SCOPE_LOB).toString();** I'm getting data like below

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p class="00Normal" style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt 24.3pt"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Start: 8:30 am
    <!--?xml:namespace prefix = o ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" /-->
    <o:p></o:p></span></p> 
  <p class="00Normal" style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt 24.3pt"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">End: 4 pm
    <o:p></o:p></span></p> 
  <p class="00Normal" style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt 24.3pt"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">The goal of this visit is to conduct an intial assessment of systems and processes in place to support supply of materials for GMP clinical development and manufacturing of pharmaceuticals.<span style="mso-spacerun: yes"> </span>A cGMP assessment of specific processes, procedures, ad the general quality systems will occur as outlined below.<span style="mso-spacerun: yes"> </span>The following items represent the scope and visit focus areas:
    <o:p></o:p></span></p> 
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt 60.3pt; TEXT-INDENT: -0.25in; tab-stops: list 60.3pt; mso-list: l120 level1 lfo139"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; mso-bidi-font-weight: bold">1.<span style="FONT: 7pt 'Times New Roman'"> </span></span><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; mso-bidi-font-weight: bold">SOP Program
    <o:p></o:p></span></p> 
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt 0.9in; TEXT-INDENT: -22.5pt"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; mso-bidi-font-weight: bold"> 
    <o:p></o:p></span></p> 
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt 60.3pt; TEXT-INDENT: -0.25in; tab-stops: list 60.3pt; mso-list: l120 level1 lfo139"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; mso-bidi-font-weight: bold">2.<span style="FONT: 7pt 'Times New Roman'"> </span></span><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; mso-bidi-font-weight: bold">Training Program
    <o:p></o:p></span></p> 
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt 0.9in; TEXT-INDENT: -22.5pt"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; mso-bidi-font-weight: bold"> 
    <o:p></o:p></span></p> 
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt 60.3pt; TEXT-INDENT: -0.25in; tab-stops: list 60.3pt; mso-list: l120 level1 lfo139"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; mso-bidi-font-weight: bold">3.<span style="FONT: 7pt 'Times New Roman'"> </span></span><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; mso-bidi-font-weight: bold">Calibration/Preventive Maintenance Program
    <o:p></o:p></span></p> 
 </body>
</html>
```

When I use  **Jsoup.parse(AUDIT_SCOPE_LOB).text();**   I'm getting data like below

```
Start: 8:30 am End: 4 pm The goal of this visit is to conduct an intial assessment of systems and processes in place to support supply of materials for GMP clinical development and manufacturing of pharmaceuticals. A cGMP assessment of specific processes, procedures, ad the general quality systems will occur as outlined below. The following items represent the scope and visit focus areas: 1. SOP Program 2. Training Program 3. Calibration/Preventive Maintenance Program
```

I dont know much about java.
Can i get java code to extract data using jsoup and retrun the outpu like below

```
Start: 8:30 am
End: 4 pm
The goal of this visit is to conduct an intial assessment of systems and processes in place to support supply of materials for GMP clinical development and manufacturing of pharmaceuticals. A cGMP assessment of specific processes, procedures, ad the general quality systems will occur as outlined below. The following items represent the scope and visit focus areas:
1. SOP Program
2. Training Program
3. Calibration/Preventive Maintenance Program
```

Actually this data is a sample data. I have data with html tags which are not mentioned here.

Comment: `"Can i get java code to extract data using jsoup and retrun the outpu like below"` -- yes, but the first source for that code should be you and your attempt. This is not a "please give me code" type site but rather a question/answer site. You will want to study the JSoup tutorials, learn Java and JSoup and then at least attempt a solution before asking, and then show your attempt with your asking. This will allow you to ask a much more specific and answerable question. Luck.

Comment: BTW, when I meant show your attempt, I meant a real attempt, one that shows that you've studied the tutorials, something much more substantial then the line of code you've posted above.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - I think that the OP does show a real attempt for solving his problem. If AUDIT_SCOPE_LOB is a string, then applying those 2 attempts does give the output he provided, and thats why I've answered him.

Comment: @Hovercrft full of eels thanks fort your time. Actually I'm an informatica resource. I heard the name Jsoup , after searching for solution for that html issue. Then I imported Jsoup jar file and tried something..Even I don't have environment like Eclipse to write Java code and test.

Answer (score 1):

Since the information is divided between `<p>` tags, you have to select all of these tags, and print their text one by one, assuming that AUDIT_SCOPE_LOB is a valid Java `String`:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(AUDIT_SCOPE_LOB);
    Elements el = doc.select("p");
    for (Element e : el) {
        System.out.println(e.text());
    }
```

Comment: like the tag "p" , I have to handle all the tags r8?

Comment: I don't know what is r8 tag, but if it is structured like the p tag, then yes.

Comment: In just asked like the "p" , I have to handle all the tags?

Answer (score 1):

`org.jsoup.nodes.Element.toString()` returns [`org.jsoup.nodes.Element.outerHTML()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#outerHtml--)

> Get the outer HTML of this node.

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Element.text()
```

> Gets the combined text of this element and all its children.
>   Whitespace is normalized and trimmed.

So invoking `toString()` on your entire sample will return the same as output.  Likewise, invoking `text()` will return all the text without the markup, as a single String.  However, what you want is individual Strings for each paragraph of text.

---

Some of your paragraph tags are empty.  In order to get the output in your example, you should validate each paragraph has text first.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(AUDIT_SCOPE_LOB, "UTF-8");

for (Element p : doc.select("p"))
    if (p.hasText())
        System.out.println(p.text());
```

**Output**

```
Start: 8:30 am
End: 4 pm
The goal of this visit is to conduct an intial assessment of systems and processes in place to support supply of materials for GMP clinical development and manufacturing of pharmaceuticals. A cGMP assessment of specific processes, procedures, ad the general quality systems will occur as outlined bel ow. The following items represent the scope and visit focus areas:
1. SOP Program
2. Training Program
3. Calibration/Preventive Maintenance Program
```

---

Take a look at [CSS Selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) for more examples of how to parse out your data. For instance, if you wanted to parse out the ordered list, you could select on the class name and retrieve the 2nd span in the list.

```
for (Element span : doc.select("p.MsoNormal > span:nth-child(2)")) 
     System.out.println(span.ownText());
```

**Output**

```
SOP Program
Training Program
Calibration/Preventive Maintenance Program
```